# Is it possible to get SimpleMembership to call a web service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

My web database server is being moved from the DMZ to the company LAN (don't ask why!). The downside of this is that my MVC 4 website is now gonna have to talk to an app server with web services (or web api) to get to the database.   This isn't a major headache for most of my stuff,  but I'm using the SimpleMembershipProvider for user authentication and that seems to need direct access to the database.
Is there any way to get SimpleMembership to talk to a web service or do I have to use a custom membership provider instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with the same situation, and while I haven't written or tested the code yet, I'll be writing a class to inherit from SimpleMembershipProvider and overriding the methods to call methods from the service (web api).

Is this the approach you ended up using?